# Can a Preemptive instance be changed to non-Preemptive

Tags: instance, preemptive

I created a Preemptive instance to test out the GCP.  I can't find a way to turn Preemptive off and basically migrate the instance to a normal one.

Can I turn Preemptive off or do I need to create a brand new instance...and loose some of my testing work?